# Trying to get logged in User's `ID` using `HttpContextAccessor` but getting null reference on production server (Blazor)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm trying to get the currently logged-in User his ID using `IHttpContextAccessor`. Now I've implemented this in my Blazor App. Now, this works fine when testing this locally, but when deployed on an actual server I get null references.

The following function should get the whole user, which holds its ID.

```cs
private readonly AspNetUserManager developerUserManager;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

public UserService(AspNetUserManager _developerUserManager, IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor)
{
   this.developerUserManager = _developerUserManager;
   this.contextAccessor = _contextAccessor;
}
public async Task<AspNetUser> GetLoggedInUser()
{
   AspNetUser user = await developerUserManager.GetUserAsync(contextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
   return user;
}
//My User model
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public string Function { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string FullName => $"{FirstName + LastName}";
    }
```

As mentioned before, when testing locally (localhost:1111) this works with no problems and acts as should.
But when deployed on a server and go to a page that tries to use this function the DevTools console greets me with null references.

`Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at TerceraDeveloperSite.Services.UserService.GetLoggedInUser() in /builds/xxllnc/tercera/2.0-tercera-apps/tercera-developer-site/Services/UserService.cs:line 54 at TerceraDeveloperSite.Pages.Main.Page.MyPages.OnInitializedAsync() in /builds/xxllnc/tercera/2.0-tercera-apps/tercera-developer-site/Pages/Main/Page/MyPages.razor.cs:line 45 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)`

In this case, it's complaining about this function where it's null.

```cs
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {

            await documentationPageService.GetDocumentationPages();
            await categoryService.GetCategories();
            await categoryPageService.GetCategoryPages();

            AspNetUser user = await userService.GetLoggedInUser();

            if (user != null)
            {
                foreach (CategoryPage cp in categoryPageService.CategoryPages)
                {
                    foreach (DocumentationPage doc in documentationPageService.DocumentationPages)
                    {
                        if(cp.PageId == doc.Id && cp.Published && cp.UserId == user.Id)
                        {
                            MyPublishedPagesList.Add(cp);
                        }
                        else if(cp.PageId == doc.Id && cp.Published == false && cp.UserId == user.Id)
                        {
                            MyUnPublishedPagesList.Add(cp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I've also tried using `AuthenticationStateTask` but this too resulted in similar issues.

I'd to know if it were possible to perhaps debug inside the DevTools console or something else to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Don't use httpcontextaccessor. In blazor, always use CascadingAuthenticationState.

Comment: @MayurEkbote How would I be able to reference this in my `razor.cs` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter

Comment: As far as I know, this only gives me access to really limited information, I'd like to get the information from the whole "User" model, which I also showed inside my question, this info is mainly accessed from the database.

Comment: You get a specific value associated with the user (like Object ID) and then use it as a look up to fetch additional info from the db

Comment: Ah, I managed to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched out `HttpContextAccessor` for the `AuthenticationStateProvider` and changed my function as followed.

```cs
private async Task<AspNetUser> GetLoggedInUser()
{
   AuthenticationState authState = await authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

   return await userManager.GetUserAsync(authState.User);
}
```

The `UserManager` function also takes `ClaimPrincipals` so this was actually quite an easy fix.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? This worked just fine.

Comment: @enet Weird, I've never really had any problems regarding that stuff. It always has worked fine for me.